# Machine 32-bit Word to Decimal Conversion

Tags: arithmetic, binary, floating-point

Given the machine 32-bit word `1100 0001 1011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`
can I find the decimal number represented by this word assuming that it is

(a) a two’s complement integer;
(b) an unsigned integer;
(c) a single precision IEEE 754 floating-point number?

Comment: What have you tried, how far did you get? It should be not hard to get a formula from the 4-bit-grouping in cases a) and b), and to identify sign, exponent and mantissa in case c).

Comment: this is part of a coursework I am working on, however I am struggling to understand if they are asking to come up with three different results, one for each point (a), (b) and (c), or it is one result that has to comply with the criteria mentioned in points (a), (b) and (c)?

Comment: also if the question asks `to find the decimal number represented by the word` it seems contradictory that (a) and (b) asks for integer results, how can the result be a decimal and an integer at the same time?

Comment: Yes, as the leading bit is set, the results for a) and b) will be different, and c) is something completely else as the bit string encodes 3 different parts. // "Decimal" refers to a number written in base 10 instead of the given base 2 representation.